# Why is my Twitter bot not authenticating?

Tags: python, api, twitter, bots, tweepy

I have been following a tutorial directly, as well as cross referencing with tweepy documentation and my code is still not authorizing to Twitters' API. I have quadruple checked my key, secrets, and tokens. I've even changed the which variables go where. Anytime I try to use the authentication methods found in the #graveyard it tells me the authentication failed. Where am I going wrong?

```py
import tweepy
import time

consumer_key = 'xxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxx'
#bearertoken = "xxx"
access_token = 'xxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxx'
#authenticate to twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
#create api object
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

##create tweet
#api.update_status('test run good')




#GRAVEYARD
#if api.verify_credentials():
#    print("Success")
#else:
#    print("authentication failed")
#try:
#    api.verify_credentials()
#    print("authentication ok")
#except:
#    print("authentication failed")
```

Comment: Does your Twitter app have Essential access or Elevated access? Check on the Twitter Developer Portal. Essential access only provides access to v2 endpoints, so the `verify_credentials` call will not work, even though you may have successfully authenticated.

Comment: Essential, didn't realize that was a higher access function. Thanks. Is ".update_status" higher access as well? The terminal returns I need Elevated access as well

Comment: It's not exactly "higher" access, it just means that you get access to the v1.1 API (which is no longer the current version, so you only get v2 with the starter Essential access).